# Convert milliseconds numeric to time MM:SS then sum

Tags: r, class, datetime, time

Suggestions of an alternative to the hms package to convert numeric to MM:SS that would give a different class than difftime.

Take the following example, I want to convert the variable y in the data.frame (currently in milliseconds) to a time format MM:SS for a later sum.

```
library(hms)

x <- c('a','b')
y = c(256733,249800)
z <- data.frame(x,y)

z$y <- z$y/1000

z$y  <- as.hms(z$y)
class(z$y)

sum(z$y)
```

This currently returns...

Time difference of 506.533 secs

The time variable should end up being:

04:16
04:09

sum(z$y) = 08:26

Answer (score 0):

You can use lubridate package. The dplyr package is just for easier data manipulation.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

# 1 milisecond = 0.001 second
mili_sec <- 0.001

x <- c('a','b')
y <- c(256733,249800)
z <- data.frame(x,y)
z <- z %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(y = y*mili_sec,
                y = lubridate::seconds_to_period(y),
                y = lubridate::parse_date_time(y, "%M %S"),
                H = base::format(y,"%M"),
                S = base::format(y,"%S"))
z
```

```
> z
  x                   y  H  S
1 a 0000-01-01 00:04:17 04 17
2 b 0000-01-01 00:04:10 04 10
```

```
endM <- sum(as.numeric(z$H))
endS <- sum(as.numeric(z$S))
base::format(lubridate::parse_date_time(paste(endM, endS), "%M %S"), "%M:%S")
```

```
[1] "08:27"
```

Comment: You can even the skip the first step by using `round(seconds_to_period(milliseconds(y)))`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using `lubridate::dmilliseconds`

```
z$y1 <- dmilliseconds(z$y)
  x      y                       y1
1 a 256733 256.733s (~4.28 minutes)
2 b 249800   249.8s (~4.16 minutes)

> sum(z$y1)
[1] 506.533
```

Use `seconds_to_period` to transfer `y1` to MM:SS format.